# Why do the pedal triangle's sides trace out a straight line when reflected but not other inscribed triangles?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I'm reading [this explanation](https://books.google.com/books?id=Y_9ZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA29&lpg=PA30&dq=h.a.%20schwartz%20pedal%20triangle%20proof&source=bl&ots=Td5AMwNajN&sig=wunsA4sBHsp8vRwrJOr_tT797lw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIpv6q7YLcAhUTO30KHVvgCxcQ6AEwAXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) of why the pedal triangle has the smallest perimeter of any triangle you can inscribe in an acute triangle. The figure in that linked page (Fig. 21) shows a pedal triangle $EFG$ and some other triangle $UVW$ both inscribed in a bigger, acute triangle $ABC$. The triangle $ABC$ is then reflected six times as shown, and the inscribed triangles are reflected along with it.

My question is:
Why can't there be another, non-pedal triangle whose perimeter (well, two times the perimeter) also traces out a straight line when we reflect it?

(Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm just reading this book for fun and couldn't figure out why we needed the sides to be the altitudes for the sides to form a straight line when reflection.)

Comment: this is because the path from one of the vertices of the pedal triangle to one of the other vertices of the pedal triangle is the shortest path that touches the corresponding side of the original triangle. And the shortest path between two points is a straight line. None other inscribed triangle has this property (only one line exists to connect two points)

Comment: Thanks for responding! And all right, I think I get what you mean by we can only make one line that connect those two specific points. What if we used a different line (parallel and of the same length) and tried to make the sides trace out that new line? How do we know we can't get a triangle to do that? (Or how do we know it's congruent to the pedal triangle and doesn't just have the same perimeter?)

Comment: Because of the angles! Take a look at one of the vertices of the pedal triangle. The angles between two sides of a pedal triangle and the side of the original triangle are equal, similar to how the light reflects from the mirror.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation!